# Why didn't Bane look for "The Bat"?

Tags: the-dark-knight-rises

We know there was more than one "Bat" (the flying craft), because towards the end of *The Dark Knight Rises*, the engineers tell Fox that the autopilot was fixed. We also know Fox kept all the gadgets under one roof.

So when Bane blasted his way into Applied Sciences vault, where he took all the Bat Mobiles, why didn't Bane take the Bat? Or if the Bat was not there, why didn't Bane go looking for it, as we know he was very much aware of it.

[image: Bane in the vault]

Comment: I am not sure the engineers knowing the autopilot was fixed would prove the existence of more than one Bat. The software could be in an online repository where the engineers would have found it fixed.

Comment: First, your logic is flawed, as pointed out above.  Second, asking for motivation of a character in a film is somewhat sketchy; it reminds me of the old, "Why didn't The Fellowship just fly those giant eagles into Mordor?"  It happened (or didn't happen) because that's what was necessary to propel the story.  Maybe he just needed the Bat Mobiles as he had no intention of an air war?  Maybe he didn't know how to fly it?  Maybe he forgot about it?  No one knows.  It's not expressly written into the plot, so any answer is pure speculation.